# Monitor Infinispan 7.0.3 memory

Tags: jmx, infinispan, jolokia

I'd like to use something like the jolokia application to get memory usage details with an URL like http://127.0.0.1:8080/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Perm%20Gen .

Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinispan 8 brings a new web-based management console, which gives you memory usage details for the nodes in the cluster. For more information see http://blog.infinispan.org/2015/12/infinispan-810final-is-out.html . Please note that the console is currently actively developed and may thus miss features / contain a lot of bugs.

For Infinispan 7, you'll need to do the monitoring yourself.